# pgrouting 2 pgr_createTopology not populating source and target field

Tags: postgis, pgrouting

I trying to integrate pgrouting 2.x. I am now using pgrouting 1.x. In version 1 I used `assign_vertex_id`. It already dropped in version 2 and became `pgr_createTopology` function

```
SELECT pgr_createTopology('roads_r', 0.00001, 'the_geom', 'gid')
```

It returning query result OK but its not populating source and target field of my road data. Is there any bug in this function?

Comment: We are also facing the same issue. Did you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

This is hard to tell because I can't reproduce your problem without some sample data. Would it be possible for you to send a small sample data set to the developer mailing list? http://lists.osgeo.org/mailman/listinfo/pgrouting-dev